# Is it possible to replace Funq completely in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

An established project that I am working on is look to start replacing WCF\ASMX Web Services with web services provided by ServiceStack.

The project already uses an existing IoC container extensively and there is no desire to introduce Funq into the mix.

I understand that ServiceStack can support an additional container via the Container Adapter, however the preference would be to swap IoC containers completely.

Is it possible to swap Funq entirely with another IoC implementation in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Using the `Container.Adapter` is how you can get Funq to resolve dependencies from an alternative IOC as described [in the IOC docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container).

Funq is an extremely lightweight IOC (effectively just wraps .NET generic collections) most of which is contained in this single [Container.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Funq/Container.cs) file. ServiceStack interfaces with Funq, which if an Adapter is provided, will resolve its dependencies from the specified IOC, otherwise it falls back and looks in its own collections.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I suspected that was the case, just seeing if there was a way to not add more to the cognitive load of our system by adding a another IoC container.